# Updating status on delete from another table (Oracle SQL)

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

**How can I merge these two queries?**

```
delete from login where email='test@test.com' and date_created > created_date + interval '1' day;

update staff set status_id=1 where staff.email=login.email;
```

Comment: What do you mean "merge these two queries"?  You're deleting from one table and updating another so you're going to need two separate queries.  You can obviously put both queries in a single stored procedure.  And presumably use a parameter for the email address that is referenced in both statements.

Comment: @JustinCave my english is very week. Perhaps I want to say how can I make these two queries as one? Can you provide any example code for the procedure you mentioned